# Mysql Query to get booking availability for reservation system

Tags: php, mysql

I have two database tables 
 1). Table structure
 2). Booking table

I want to get availability of booking table for current date and time.

**Table structure**

[image: Table structure]

**Booking Table**

[image: Booking table]

When i request table availability for date 2014-11-05 and booking time at 11:00:00 it should compare booking table with table structure and display only available tables. 
I need Mysql Query to perform this operation..

Comment: Hi, your code so far? =)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Are `min_table`, `table_description`, `no_people`, `food_time`, `booking_date`, and `booking_time` relevant to this problem?

Comment: those are extra fields . so they are not relevant for this problem

Comment: @JayBlanchard.  I getting all the tables from table structure table  and storing into array 1 and getting tables from booking table using where clause ( booking date and time ) and storing into array 2. I using array_duplicate ( a1, a2) and showing booking availability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `bookingtable.restaurant_table`,
    `bookingtable.no_people`,
    `bookingtable.booking_date`,
    `bookingtable.bookingend_time`,
    `bookingtable.bookingstart_time`
FROM `bookingtable`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `bookingtable` ON `bookingtable.restaurant_table` = `tablestructure.table_no`
WHERE
    `bookingtable.booking_date` = "2014-11-05"
AND
    `bookingtable.booking_time` = "11:00:00"
```

**This is what I would do, however I would store the dates and times as UNIX timestamps personally**

Comment: +1 for storing as UNIX timestamps. Though, he might already be. PHPMyAdmin displays timestamps like that, same as datetime.

Comment: Wouldn't really know - I only really use MySQL from the command line lol!

Comment: For example i have mentioned 11:00:00 . but time could be any where in middle . booking start time and end time is there in database table. So My availability check time should compare with start and end time..

Comment: This is where **UNIX timestamps** would suit you much better